# Statistical divergence

Tags: st.statistics, it.information-theory, machine-learning, learning-theory

Does anyone know about a statistical divergence of this type?
\begin{equation}
\text{D}(P||Q) =  \frac{1}{2} \left[\text{KL}(M||P) + \text{KL}(M||Q)\right]
\end{equation}
where $M = \frac{1}{2} [P+Q]$.

This divergence is very similar to the Jensen-Shannon Divergence $\text{D}(P||Q) =  \text{KL}(P||M) + \text{KL}(Q||M)$ but where the distributions in the argument of the statistical divergence appear in the second argument of the KL divergences.

I am interested in knowing if such divergence exists in the literature and to properties of such divergence. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is J-divergence, commonly just called 'symmetrised KL divergence.'

- [Kullback, Solomon, and Richard A. Leibler. "On Information and Sufficiency." *The Annals of Mathematical Statistics* 22.1 (1951): 79-86.](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177729694)
- [Jeffreys, Harold. "An Invariant Form for the Prior Probability in Estimation Problems." *Proceedings of the Royal Society of London. Series A. Mathematical and Physical Sciences* 186.1007 (1946): 453-461.](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/abs/10.1098/rspa.1946.0056)
- [Taneja, Inder Jeet. "Information and Divergence Measures." *On Generalized Information Measures and their Applications.* Advances in Electronics and Electron Physics. Vol. 76. Academic Press, 1989. 327-413.](http://www.mtm.ufsc.br/~taneja/book/node21.html) (Also available here: http://www.mtm.ufsc.br/~taneja/book/node21.html)

Comment: I remember hearing this is the metric K & L originally called 'divergence', its components being called 'discriminations.' First citation seems to confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

This might help as a place to start. Sgarro has generalized the Kullback-Leibler divergence $D_{\rm KL}(Q||P)$ to multiple distributions by introducing the average divergence

$$D’(P_1,\ldots P_k)=\frac{1}{k(k-1)}\sum_{i,j=1}^k D_{\rm KL}(P_i||P_j),$$

so what you have is related to his measure of divergence by
$$
D(P,Q)=3D’(P,Q,M)-\frac12D_{\rm KL}(P||Q)
-\frac12D_{\rm KL}(Q||P)-\frac12D_{\rm KL}(P||M)
-\frac12D_{\rm KL}(Q||M).
$$
where $M=\frac12(P+Q).$

A. Sgarro, “Informational divergence and the dissimilarity of probability distributions”, *Calcolo*(18): 293–302 (1981).